# Xcode смещает отображение после компиляции

Tags: ios, xcode, view

Выставляю элементы по оси, а после компиляции такая беда.
Как исправить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо использовать constrains и выравнивать элементы по осям, в противном случае под разные телефоны дизайн UI будет выглядеть по разнлму. Посмотрик примеру вот это видео https://youtu.be/RH_Ye-8ii8E.